# Chain rule for matrix-valued functions.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

Suppose we have a function $x\mapsto A(x)$ where $A(x)$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with differentiable matrix elements $[A(x)]_{ij}=a_{ij}(x)$. Then it is natural to take
\begin{align*}
\frac{dA}{dx} := \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{d a_{11}}{dx} & \cdots & \frac{d a_{1n}}{dx}
\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots
\\
\frac{da_{n1}}{dx} & \cdots & \frac{da_{nn}}{dx}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

My question is as follows; suppose we have some function $f$ that is sufficiently "nice" (differentiable, etc.). Then, is there a "chain-rule like" expression for
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx} f(A(x)).
\end{align*}
For example, is there a general criterion for when we can write
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx} f(A(x)) = \frac{d f(A)}{dA}\frac{dA}{dx} ?
\end{align*}

This question came to me in a more concrete example. Suppose $A(x)$ is differential, positive definite matrix for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Is there a known formula for 
$dS/dx$ where $S(x) := A^{1/2}(x)$ is the unique positive definite square root of $A(x)$? One result that follows by differentiating the expression $S^2(x) =A(x)$ is 
\begin{align*}
S(x)\frac{dS}{dx} + \frac{dS}{dx}S(x) = \frac{dA}{dx}
\end{align*}
which can be viewed as a Sylvester equation for the matrix $dS/dx$. If $S$ and $dS/dx$ commute, then this can be solved as
$$\frac{dS}{dx} = \frac{1}{2}A^{-1/2}\frac{dA}{dx}$$
which is exactly what we would get if we naively applied the chain rule. Does this Sylvester equation have a closed form solution for the general case?

Thanks!

Comment: DId you mean to say **if** $S$ and $\frac{dS}{dx}$ commute? becasue they usually do not.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Fixed the typo, thanks!

Comment: The chain rule is quite general, and in its finest form just says $d(f\circ g) = df \circ dg$. Of course, there is a fair bit of intepretation that must be done to come up with what that means in your case, which I don't have time to trace down. But rest assured that what you've written can be given a precise meaning where it (or a formula very similar) will be true.